# Microsoft's <regex> level of Unicode support?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, unicode, tr1, std

What's the `std::wregex` **Unicode** support look like for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010?

1. Does it support **Unicode character classes**? `[:Nd:]` and such.
2. Support of **collations such as digraphs**? `[.ae.]` and such.

Microsoft's implementation of [`std::wregex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982110.aspx) I am hoping is better than [boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) with regards to Unicode?

I can use the ICU library. But ICU requires a 16MB data file! I am hoping to eliminate that dependency on Windows.

**Note**: `regex` the non-wide version, only supports ASCII characters! So my hopes are not high for `wregex` the wide version, properly implementing UTF-16.

Comment: did you not just post a really similar question?

Comment: Similar, but this question is in regards to `wregex`, not `regex`. Which I am sincerely hoping has better Unicode support. I'll remove my other question and answer it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727795/does-standard-regex-library-provide-unicode-or-basicly-non-ascii-characters