# multi-byte characters in libc regcomp and regexec

Tags: regex, utf-8, glibc, libc, multibyte-functions

Is there anyway to get `libc6`'s regexp functions `regcomp` and `regexec` to work properly with multi-byte characters?

For instance, if my pattern is the utf8 characters `猫机+猫`, finding a match on the utf8 encoded string `猫机机机猫` will fail, where it should succeed.

I think this is because the character `机`'s byte representation is `\xe6\x9c\xba`, and the `+` is matching one or more of the byte `\xba`.  I can make this instance work by putting parenthesis around each multibyte character in the pattern, but since this is for an application I can't require users to do this.

Is there a way to flag a pattern or string to match as containing utf8 characters?  Perhaps telling `libc` to store the pattern as wchar instead of char?

Comment: Parens around the multi-byte char don't help?

Comment: I can do that, but I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require the user to change the pattern in such a way.  Thank you though!  I edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: Why not just use codepoints `\x{nnnnnnn}` ? That is, if the regex engine should support Unicode. Usually the regex  and target string should use the same encoding,  but its not a good idea to use literal Unicode chars within a regex string. If the engine supports it though, it reads the char in char units, not byte units.

Comment: No, these options don't work because I'm hoping to use this within an application that shouldn't require users to alter their regexps.  Does this mean there is no support for multibyte chars in libc?  Is there another extremely common c library I could use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its manual page, *glibc* understands POSIX regexp. There is no unicode support in POSIX regexp *per se*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727795/does-posix-regex-h-provide-unicode-or-basically-non-ascii-characters/8728601#answer-8728131) for an excerpt of the standard that enlightens this point. This means that you can also forget about UTF. This means also that whatever locale environment you're in, multi-byte characters won't fit.

The post I've mentionned (as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094109/using-regular-expression-with-unicode-string-in-c)) suggests you use some unicode-aware regexp library, such as *pcre*. If you're interested, *pcre* provides a fake posix interface, with the addition of a non-standard REG_UTF flag. You won't have to rewrite your code, except for the #include directive, and the addition of REG_UTF at compile step.

Hope this covers your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a regex to build your regex? Here's a javascript example, (though I know you aren't using js):

```js
function Examp () {
  var uString = "猫机+猫+猫ymg+sah猫";
  var plussed = uString.replace(/(.)(?=[\+\*])/ig,"($1)");
  console.log("Starting with string: " + uString + "\r\n" + "Result: " + plussed);
  uString = "猫机+猫*猫ymg+s\\a+I+h猫";
  plussed = uString.replace(/(\\?.)(?=[\+\*])/ig,"($1)");
  console.log("You can even take this a step further and account for a character being escaped, if that's a consideration.")
  console.log("Starting with string: " + uString + "\r\n" + "Result: " + plussed);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="Examp()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to flag a pattern or string to match as containing utf8 characters?

I suspect that `LC_CTYPE` environment variable (or other related locale settings) is the [way to make `regcomp`/`regexec` understand your encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809461/94687).

At least, `grep` program seems to take it into account, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809461/94687; I haven't tested this with `regcomp` function.